# Weblogic deployment causes - Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, weblogic, jpa-2.0

I am using Hibernate 4, Spring 3 , JSF 2.0 and Weblogic 10.3.6

When I start weblogic server and server starts successfully, however whenever it starts publishing application, I am getting the following exception.

```
   Error creating bean with name 
 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' 
  defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: 
  Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

    Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
   bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'defined in ServletContext resource 
   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
   nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
   javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/
   SharedCacheMode;

Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()
Ljavax/persistence /SharedCacheMode;    at 
org.hibernate.ejb.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInfo(LogHelper.java:38)  at
org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:525)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)     at  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManage
```

I have the following in applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">      
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.test" />
    <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
    <bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:DB" />
        <property name="user" value="scott" />
        <property name="password" value="tiger" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
    <!-- JPA Entity Manager Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.test.entity" />

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jdbc.dialectClass}" />

            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="defaultLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler" />
    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>net.test.entity.Department</value>
                <value>net.test.entity.Employees</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <!-- Transaction Config -->

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config />    

    <bean id="hibernateStatisticsMBean" class="org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService">
        <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" value="#{entityManagerFactory.sessionFactory}" />
    </bean>
    <bean name="ehCacheManagerMBean"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
        <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true" />
    </bean>    
    <bean id="jmxExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter"
        lazy-init="false">
        <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer" />
        <property name="registrationBehaviorName" value="REGISTRATION_REPLACE_EXISTING" />
        <property name="beans">
            <map>
                <entry key="SpringBeans:name=hibernateStatisticsMBean"
                    value-ref="hibernateStatisticsMBean" />
                <entry key="SpringBeans:name=ehCacheManagerMBean" value-ref="ehCacheManagerMBean" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
          http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>myappp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> 
    <name>myappp</name> 
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSF library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Primefaces library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>afterwork</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oracle Java Connector library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-extcdi-core-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies> 
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>              
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- source output directory -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

In Weblogic 10.3.6 I have enabled JPA2 support by adding the following in `commEnv.cmd`

```
@rem Enable JPA 2.0 functionality on WebLogic Server 
set PRE_CLASSPATH=%BEA_HOME%\modules\javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar;
%BEA_HOME%\modules\com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704572/dependancy-error-result-in-nosuchmethoderror-persistenceunitinfo-getsharedcache  ?

Comment: @ManjulaWeerasinge As mentioned in the post I already have the following in pom.xml `<dependency>   <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>'`

Comment: @Polppan: Just out of interest, is there a specific reason why you're using your own connection pool rather than using a weblogic datasource?

Comment: @beny23 If I would want to use weblogic datasource what I need to do? Besides does this have any relation with this error? Thanks

Comment: @Polppan: Define your datasource through the weblogic console and then use a jndi datasource in spring: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee-jndi-lookup but this is probably unrelated to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved, for Weblogic 10.3.6 exe distribution there is no `javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_2-0-0.jar`, what it has is `javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar`.

That class along with `jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-0.jar` needs to be in classpath.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is related to the classloading hierarchy and some classes are loaded from the system class loader rather than the jars included in your EAR.

In *WebLogic* Server, any .jar file present in the *system classpath* is loaded by the WebLogic Server *system classloader*. All applications running within a server instance are loaded in application classloaders which are children of the system classloader. In this implementation of the system classloader, *applications cannot use different versions of third-party jars which are already present in the system classloader*. Every child classloader asks the parent (the system classloader) for a particular class and cannot load classes which are seen by the parent.

For example, if a class called com.foo.Baz exists in both $CLASSPATH as well as the application EAR, then the class from the $CLASSPATH is loaded and not the one from the EAR. Since weblogic.jar is in the $CLASSPATH, applications can not override any WebLogic Server classes.

The *FilteringClassLoader* provides a mechanism for you to configure deployment descriptors to explicitly specify that certain packages should always be loaded from the application, rather than being loaded by the system classloader.

The *FilteringClassLoader* sits between the application classloader and the system. It is a child of the system classloader and the parent of the application classloader. The FilteringClassLoader intercepts the loadClass(String className) method and compares the className with a list of packages specified in **weblogic-application.xml** file.

In conclusion would you try to modify your weblogic-application.xml as to load some packages from the jars included in your EAR rather than the system class loader? A sample example is the following:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.apache.commons.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.apache.xmlbeans.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

Comment: Tolis, I am not deploying application to Weblogic server. In eclipse for development I have configured WLS 10.3.6 in Server. When I publish my application I am getting these exceptions. Application is working fine in another instance of same source files. I have installed a new WLS and in another machine and with this I am getting these exceptions.

Comment: Tolis Application which works on WLS 10.3.6 is http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/11g/wls/1036/wls1036_dev.zip and the one which is not working is http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/11g/wls/1036/wls1036_win32.exe in this [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/wls-main-097127.html)